# How to verify if some items are in a list?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to mess about trying the haskell equivalent of the '[Scala One Liners](http://solog.co/47/10-scala-one-liners-to-impress-your-friends/)' thing that has recently popped up on Reddit/Hacker News.

Here's what I've got so far (people could probably do them a lot better than me but these are my beginner level attempts)

https://gist.github.com/1005383

The one I'm stuck on is verifying if items are in a list. Basically the Scala example is this

```
val wordlist = List("scala", "akka", "play framework", "sbt", "typesafe")
val tweet = "This is an example tweet talking about scala and sbt."
(words.foldLeft(false)( _ || tweet.contains(_) ))
```

I'm a bit stumped how to do this in Haskell. I know you can do:

```
any (=="haskell") $ words "haskell is great!"
```

To verify if **one** of the words is present, but the Scala example asks if any of the words in the wordlist are present in the test string.

I can't seem to find a `contains` function or something similar to that. I know you could probably write a function to do it but that defeats the point of doing this task in one line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:elem) function from the Prelude which checks if an item is in a list. It is commonly used in infix form:

```
Prelude> "foo" `elem` ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
True
```

You can then use it in an operator section just like you did with `==`:

```
Prelude> let wordList = ["scala", "akka", "play framework", "sbt", "types"]
Prelude> let tweet = "This is an example tweet talking about scala and sbt."
Prelude> any (`elem` wordList) $ words tweet
True
```

---

When you find yourself needing a function, but you don't know the name, try using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to search for a function by type.

Here you wanted something that checks if a thing of any type is in a list of things of the same type, i.e. something of a type like `a -> [a] -> Bool` (you also need an `Eq` constraint, but let's say you didn't know that). Typing this type signature into Hoogle [gives you `elem` as the top result](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Bool).

Answer (score 6):

How about using `Data.List.intersect`?

```
import Data.List.intersect

not $ null $ intersect (words tweet) wordList
```

Answer (score 3):

Although there are already good answers I thought it'd be nice to write something in the spirit of your original code using `any`. That way you get to see how to compose your own complex queries from simple reusable parts rather than using off-the-shelf parts like `intersect` and `elem`:

```
any (\x -> any (\y -> (y == x)) $ words "haskell is great!")
    ["scala", "is", "tolerable"]
```

With a little reordering you can sort of read it in English: is there any word `x` in the sentence such that there is any `y` in the list such that `x == y`? It's clear how to extend to more 'axes' than two, perform comparisons other than `==`, and even mix it up with `all`.